# Type K thermocouple durability in semimolten plastic

Tags: sensor, thermocouple

I want to measure the temperature of a semi-molten piece of plastic, but for my final application I don't want to have to touch the thermocouple.  This means it will more than likely end up in the hot plastic and will be stuck there once cooled.  I will heat the plastic again to remove the thermocouple.

Will a type K glass braided thermocouple withstand any necessary scraping of plastic off of it after I remove it and still provide accurate results?  I'm not very familiar with the sensitivity of the tips.

Comment: What does the supplier say?

Answer (score 1):

Normally a plastics T/C has a 300-series stainless steel protection tube. Depend on the thickness of that tube scraping off plastic with something softer may be acceptable. Brass tools are often used so they won't damage expensive steel molds and extrusion dies.

If you can see the glass braid it isn't going to be very durable- use the type with a robust tube and armored wire- there are thousands of different types and constructions- decently made thermocouples themselves tend to be quite tough. Chemically, the compatibility is good for most plastics.